# 301 redirect matching URL is contained in target URL causing infinite redirect

Tags: regex, redirect

I need /blah/ to redirect to /blah/blah-2/. Since the target URL contains "blah" I end up with /blah/blah-2/blah-2/blah-2/blah-2/blah-2/blah-2/...

Thank you

@starkeen - Yes. I was told one of thee should work, but they don't.

```
RewriteRule seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^/seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^/?seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]
```

But I've also learned it may be WordPress getting in the way.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the code ?

Comment: @starkeen - sorry cant get code or paragrpahs to format properly...

Yes. I was told one of thee should work, but they don't.  

  RewriteRule seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]  
    RewriteRule ^/seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]  
    RewriteRule ^/?seacoast/?$ /seacoast/seacoast-events/ [R=301,L]     
   
   
But I've also learned it may be WordPress getting in the way.

Comment: Your rules are ok, and they are not causing infinite loop error. Check your other rules or wp.